# Regarding Markov's inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

I have a small doubt in Markov's inequality, it seems trivial to me but I want to be sure.Markov's inequality says that if $Y$ is a random variable (real) with expected value E(Y),then
$$P[|Y| \geq a] \leq E(|Y|)/a$$, where $a>0$. My question is that is it still true if I don't use modulus on left hand side? That is, if LHS is $P[Y\geq a]$ ?

Comment: If it is only on the left hand side, the statement should be true, since $P(Y>a)\leq P(|Y|>a)$. Notice that the absolute value on the right hand side is still required.

Comment: Instead of inequality, isn't it that $P(Y \geq a)=P(|Y| \geq a)$ because $a>0$

Comment: You can think of $Y$ such that $P(Y=-1)=P(Y=1)=1/2$ and $a\in(0,1)$, then $1/2=P(Y=1)=P(Y>a)\leq P(|Y|>a)=1\leq 1/a =E[|Y|]/a$.

Comment: @UserA:  $P(Y \geq a)+P(Y \leq -a)=P(|Y| \geq a)$ when $a > 0$

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can derive an inequality without involving $|u|$. Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and the random variable $u$. We have
$$\mu(u\geq a)=\frac{1}{a}\int a\mathbb{I}_{\{u\geq a\}}d\mu\leq \frac{1}{a}\int u\mathbb{I}_{\{u\geq a\}}d\mu $$
Now if $u$ were such that $u \geq 0$ then we would have
$$\int u\mathbb{I}_{\{u\geq a\}}d\mu \leq \int ud\mu =E[u]$$
yielding Markov's inequality. So for general $u$ we can do
$$\mu(u\geq a) \leq \frac{1}{a}E[u\mathbb{I}_{\{u\geq a\}}]$$
For the original question, as noted in the comments, since
$$\{u\geq a\}\subset \{u\geq a\}\cup\{u\leq -a\}=\{|u|\geq a\}$$
by the properties of measures it follows that $\mu(u\geq a)\leq \mu(|u|\geq a)$, but the expectation on the rhs of Markov's inequality will still involve $|u|$.